# Clear Cell Value based on Condition of another Cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Cell `A1:A6` has a User Fed value, Cell `B1:B6` has a formula, Cell `C1:C6` has a result
If Cell A1 value is deleted, Can the content be cleared from `C1`, I tried this but its not working.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A6")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("C1:C6").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below codes-

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A6")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "" Or Target = Null Then
            Target.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
            'Target.Offset(0, 2) = ""
            'Range("C1:C6").ClearContents
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This one gives an Run Time error 13 Type Mismatch, tried this code in "ThisWorkbook" Code Window as well as "Sheet1" Code Window, also tried removing the commented part in yr code but no go

Comment: I have tested the code then post as answer. So, no chance to get any error. Can you post your full code so that we can check.